# How to do hourly location updates?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I'm building a location-based app, but I hate having the location services icon on. I only need coordinates once per hour, but I can't figure out how to do this without saying the app is a VoIP app. Is it possible to do this in a way that's App Store acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location` in the `UIBackgroundModes` of your app, [see the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

About the location services icon on, I think you should leave it. It's a fair feedback for your user. A user has to know its position is being tracked and leaving the icon on for a few seconds each time the geolocation actually happens wouldn't be fair. (and it sounds like a case of app rejection to me).

As long as you don't have a negative impact on the device battery, the user will be grateful you let it know you're tracking his position.

For instance, apps such as OpenPaths made my iPhone show the location icon on all the time and have no real negative impact on the battery.

Comment: As a user I’m a bit nervous about the icon sticking up there for longer periods of time. I know that it might be just the significant location updates thing that does not drain the battery, but with regular users it’s a huge support issue waiting to happen. In this regard I understand the poster’s need to only display the icon when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I feel the same way. We're not tracking them anyway we just want hourly updates? How is this possible

Comment: “we just want hourly updates" = that's tracking :) - Anyway, I think it is some iOS feature that you can't manage programatically. And, as a user, I'm glad it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would register for significant location change updates. When updates happen compare timestamp with last update. Use update if time delta > 60 minutes. Worst case: I **believe** you get the location indicator outline. this tells the user that a kind of tracking is happening — but not all the time, so it' not a battery issue and you don't get too many support requests. Best case: Registering for significant location change update doesn't show the indicator outline. But I am not certain. Completely without icon might just not be possible.